# Metadata registry Software - alternative to Aristotle Cloud

Tags: metadata, iso

Good morning,

I am at the point of writing my master thesis on ISO11179 compliant metadata registries. Part of it is a comparison of commercial metadata creation tools.

However, it is not about analysing this data, but defining it as in Aristotle cloud. However, apart from this tool, I have not found any alternative. Can anyone help me?

Best regards,
Iwona

Comment: To be honest, SO is not place for asking for alternatives or opinions, but to solve programming problems, like uknkown error, understand stacktrace, etc, etc. I'm not an expert in metadata systems, but it looks like very early, and specific niche. AFAIK it is only storing and processing data, so it's relatively easy to create your own metadata registry.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and hint. Probably you are right and there exists any software, which helps to create matadata registry.